# How to stop only the Mysql server in MAMP PRO?

Tags: mysql, mamp

I need to stop Mysql server in MAMP PRO and keep Apache running. How can I do that ?

There is a stop button available but it stops all services.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out...

There is a shell script for that: /Applications/MAMP/bin/stopMysql.sh

If you changed your root password you have to edit this file and change the password in it.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570010/how-start-stop-mamp-pro-using-command-line/19801925#19801925

You can just use the portion to start/stop MySQL.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.